# How to link gnuplot to c++

Tags: c++, gnuplot

What would be the code to plot a simple sin x graph in c++?
i tried this...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
  FILE *gnuplotPipe = popen("C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot -persist","w");


if (gnuplotPipe) {

fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "plot sin(x)");
fflush(gnuplotPipe);

}
}
```

but i get this error....
c:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command

Do i have to configur linker settings or anything else?? Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `popen("\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot,\" -persist","w");`

Comment: You are not "linking" gnuplot here.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the file name because it contains a space.

```
popen("\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot\" -persist","w");
```

You have one set of quotes because it's a string literal, but that string has to contain more quotes because of the space.

Comment: Thanks everyone...it finally worked but it insteads just opens gnuplot automatically. I again have to manually enter 'plot sin(x)'. How should i code it so that it runs automatically and just shows me the sin(x) graph